# Programmatically create new category in magento

Tags: magento

I just want to create new category programmatically in magento. I have a code and tried this but can't success.

code is here:

```
<?php
$parentId = '2';

$category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
$category->setName('check');
$category->setUrlKey('new-category');
$category->setIsActive(1);
$category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
$category->setIsAnchor(0);

$parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
$category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());              

$category->save();
unset($category);

?>
```

actually the problem with this code whenever I tried it than it create new category but can't set is_active yes in admin.

Answer (score 7):

Please set Store id for that category. To code out side magento page, use codes below:

```
try{
    $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
    $category->setName('check');
    $category->setUrlKey('new-category');
    $category->setIsActive(1);
    $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
    $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active achor
    $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
    $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
    $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
    $category->save();
} catch(Exception $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

Comment: The File is in the app//design/frontend/default/testing/page/html/addcategory.phtml.

i tried your code but it can't work.

Comment: I tried require '/var/www/magentofortesting/app/Mage.php' in my file because i have linux operating system than the path for the file is this.so again it can't work.

Comment: i tried your code , the code working as it is that old one work ,the problem with the code is , it can't set the value setIsActive(1). so that whenever new category create than new category never set to enable.

Comment: Please, use for display mode defined constant Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PAGE, Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_PRODUCT or Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::DM_MIXED

Answer (score 0):

Please refer my tutorial which explains how to create the category and subcategories pro-grammatically.

```
function addManufacturers( $manufacturers ) {
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
$parentId = '2';
$list = array();

foreach ($manufacturers as  $key => $manufacturer) {
    try {

        $enabled = 1;
        if ($key == 0) {
            $parentId = '2';
        }
        else {
            $parentId = $list[0];
        }

        $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category');
        $category->setName($manufacturer);
        $category->setMetaTitle($manufacturer);
        $category->setIncludeInMenu(1);
        $category->setUrlKey(strtolower($manufacturer));
        $category->setDescription(strip_tags($manufacturer));
        $category->setMetaDescription($manufacturer);
        $category->setMetaKeywords($manufacturer);
        $category->setIsActive($enabled);
        $category->setDisplayMode('PRODUCTS');
        $category->setIsAnchor(1); //for active anchor
        $category->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId());
        $parentCategory = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($parentId);
        $category->setPath($parentCategory->getPath());
        $category->setCustomUseParentSettings(true);
        $category->save();
        $list[$key] = $category->getId();
        echo 'Category ' . $category->getName() . ' ' . $category->getId() . ' imported successfully' . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Something failed for category ' . $manufacturer . PHP_EOL;
        print_r($e);
    }
}
return $list;
```

}

http://www.pearlbells.co.uk/how-to-create-new-categories-and-assigned-products-to-category-programmatically-magento/

Comment: This answer relies completely on the content of external links (you have included a snippet here, but it's very short). Should they ever become invalid, your answer would be useless. So please [edit] your answer and add at least a summary of what can be found there. Thank you!